# Controlling Sensor ISO and Exposure time in android camera2API

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to add in Manual Camera Controls new exposure value and ISO values. I am using the Camera2Basic Example. The problem I face now is that I am new to Android. I tried looking at L-Camera but its in Scala and that confuses me further.

I tried the following changes but there was no update to the preview of the image.

```
 private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder
                = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {
                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);

                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME,Long.valueOf("100000"));
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY,1600);

                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        showToast("Failed");
                    }
                }, null
        );
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you must change your template to `TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE` or `TEMPLATE_MANUAL` to see the values change in the preview. Also, remember to set your `CONTROL_AE_MODE` and 'CONTROL_MODE' to OFF.

> This control is only effective if android.control.aeMode or android.control.mode is set to OFF; otherwise the auto-exposure algorithm will override this value.

From [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html)

Second, set your values with:

```
builder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, isoValue);
builder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, exposureTimeValueInMilliseconds);
```

Finally after all the changes don't forget to update your preview using a `CaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest`

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Just a quick point that had me held up. Exposure time is measured not in milliseconds but nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

So I have made the following changes to my code.

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder
    = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);


mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,
    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);

mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);

mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME,Long.valueOf("22000"));
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY,200);

mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

However I get a weird preview with a lot of green light taken as an input.

Here it is https://postimg.org/image/yl95e6qht/

This is what it looks like using my inbuilt camera app: https://postimg.org/image/lvjnwquj5/

Comment: Set to auto "CONTROL_AWB_MODE" or disable it.

Comment: No it didn't. I guess its something to do with the frame rate. DO I need to set that? Is there anywhere I can contact you with my doubts?

Comment: you have my email in my profile. Let me know if i can help u in something there and i will try it

Comment: Hey. I couldn't find your email in the profile. Where should I look for it!

Comment: Could you please help me to solve my the same issue... I have spent maybe 5 days without success.. I need to set up my iso, but every step i get different issues... Maybe if you have code sample how you eventually solved this issue it will help not only me. Because as you know there are just few samples about camera2api and almost any about how to set up your custom settings...

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the problem:

```
mPreviewBuilder.set(
    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, 
    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with green captures when using manual exposure with camera 2 API.
I could fix it by only deactivating `CONTROL_AE_MODE` instead of both `CONTROL_AE_MODE` and `CONTROL_MODE`.
This is my configuration:

```
final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);

captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, Long.valueOf("8000000")); // 8000000 ns = 8 ms
```